# jQuery scroll down and up not working on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile

I am using jQuery to detect when a user scrolls the mousewheel down or up. here is my code:

```
$(window).bind('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', function(event){
    if (event.originalEvent.wheelDelta > 0 || event.originalEvent.detail < 0) {
        // scroll up
    }
    else {
        // scroll down
    }
});
```

I just realized this doesn't work with mobile swiping up or down. Is there a way I can modify the code so that it works on mobile too?

Answer (score 0):

You can actually this using jQuery scroll function and compare the last scroll position to the current scroll position if it's lesser the user is scrolling down otherwise up

```js
var last_pos= 0;

$(window).scroll(function () {
    var current_pos= $(this).scrollTop();
    if (current_pos > last_pos) {
        alert('down');
    } else {
        alert('up');
    }
    last_pos = current_pos;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>test</h1><h1>test</h1><h1>test</h1><h1>test</h1><h1>test</h1><h1>test</h1><h1>test</h1><h1>test</h1><h1>test</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

For mobile you have scrollstart and scrollstop, you don't have up or down so you have to do it yourself :P

Check this: [jQuery Mobile: Make the header hide on scroll down and show on scroll up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21249276/jquery-mobile-make-the-header-hide-on-scroll-down-and-show-on-scroll-up)

You have a snippet there you can easily edit for what you need!